# Three.js: Weird render result

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

**How can I fix the reflection around the cycles?**

I got some weird results on my object. I hope the pictures show the problem.

**Three.js result**

[image]
[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

[image]

```
loader.load( "model.js", function(geometry){
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
      color: 0xffffff,
      specular: 0xffffff,
      shininess: 65,
      metal: true,
      envMap: cubeCamera.renderTarget
    }));
    scene.add(mesh);
    });
```

I have exported the model with the three.js json exporter from blender. The model has vertices, faces and UVs.

Comment: For an example of accurate, close reflections, see http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_mirror.html

Comment: I will implement this. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like your cubemap is not updated as the animation plays. The cube map has to be carefully placed, and also has to move with the animation to stay accurate. Using the cubecamera is not the best choice in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, this is hard to explain, but basically it is because you are using triangle polygons and your topology is not good. 
It is often referred to as "pinching" if I recall correctly.
When modelling for Three.js, it is basically modelling for a game engine and all the same rules need to be followed.

Things you could try to get a better reflection:

- Reduce the amount of polygons as it seems you have WAY more polygons than are needed.
- Try for a cleaner topology using quads and minimising tris.
- Set up smoothing groups

An easy fix would be to use a simple plane in the correct shape with holes cut out as it seems the sides are not really visible anyway. (I am talking about the large flat piece specifically here). I suggest this because I have found that reflections when using MeshPhongMaterial are often not adversely affected by the use of ngons and tris when all the vertices are flat and in the same smoothing group.